# Prevent CSS Stylesheet From Applying to Certain Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the bootstrap CSS framework for one of the pages on my site. The problem is that the CSS styling that is included with Bootstrap messes up the formatting for my sidebar in that it changes the color, font-size, font-family, etc... Is there a way I can make everything in my sidebar id not affected by bootstrap CSS, even if for example, there are CSS rules for h1 and I have h1 headings in my sidebar?

**What I've Tried that did not work**

I initially went through Bootstrap CSS and trying to eliminate whatever CSS rules were causing the problem but the CSS was too lengthy, and removing certain styling that was causing the issue had other adverse effects.

I tried customizing what bootstrap styles were downloaded but it still messed up my sidebar

I tried adding inline styling to every element to over-ride Bootstrap styling, but for some reason, the sidebar still didn't look the same.

This leads me to the conclusion that the best solution is to somehow prevent Bootstrap styling from affecting the sidebar. How, if possible can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be if you manually add 'reset' properties to your sidebar.

Bootstrap would still apply its styles to all sidebars, however if the element id is `#yoursidebar`, you can reset everything that bootstrap does.

```
#yoursidebar {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    /* ...and anything else needed to reset bootstrap styles... */

    /* ...add your custom style here...... */

}
```

Comment: Could you just clarify what you mean by "reset everything that bootstrap does"? It sounds like this is on the right track.

Comment: check this link: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ you must know which properties bootstrap is apply and 'revert/reset' them.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own class to the sidebar and then style it using that class.

The better way: not to change the bootstrap core files.  Add a new stylesheet and then call it in the header after the bootstrap stylesheet. The second one (such as custom.css) would override the bootstrap styles.

Comment: I tried doing that but it still wouldn't solve the problem. I even just moved my main.css to after the bootstrap css in the heading but for whatever reason it did not work. Perhaps there were certain more specific styles in bootstrap, or styles that were given more weight if that is possible. I even tried adding !important

Comment: Could you send me the link so I can take a look?

Comment: www.ninjawarrior.info and the issue is with the sidebar (you can see it if you click the hamburger icon for menu and then click one of the images). Then go to www.ninjawarrior.info/obstacles.html and do the same thing and note the difference between the sidebars.